# How to create a pipeline for PCA?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, pipeline, pca

I'm working on some `customer_data` where I, as a first step, want to do PCA, followed by clustering as a second step.

Since there needs to be done encoding (and scaling) before feeding the data to the PCA, I thought it would be good to fit it all into a pipeline. - Which unfortunately doesn't seem to work.

How can I create this pipeline, and does it even make sense to do it like this?

```
# Creating pipeline objects 
encoder = OneHotEncoder(drop='first')
scaler = StandardScaler(with_mean=False)
pca = PCA()

# Create pipeline
pca_pipe = make_pipeline(encoder,
                         scaler,
                         pca)

# Fit data to pipeline
pca_pipe.fit_transform(customer_data_raw)
```

I get the following error message:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-27-c4ce88042a66> in <module>()
     20 
     21 # Fit data to pipeline
---> 22 pca_pipe.fit_transform(customer_data_raw)

2 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/sklearn/decomposition/_pca.py in _fit(self, X)
    385         # This is more informative than the generic one raised by check_array.
    386         if issparse(X):
--> 387             raise TypeError('PCA does not support sparse input. See '
    388                             'TruncatedSVD for a possible alternative.')
    389 

TypeError: PCA does not support sparse input. See TruncatedSVD for a possible alternative.
```

Comment: What doesn't work?  If there's an error message, please provide (in the question) the full error traceback.  Otherwise, provide an example of desired and actual behavior.

Comment: I get the following error:

`TypeError: PCA does not support sparse input. See TruncatedSVD for a possible alternative.`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`OneHotEncoder` creates a sparse matrix on transform by default.  From there the error message is pretty straightforward: you can try `TruncatedSVD` instead of `PCA`.  However, you could also set `sparse=False` in the encoder if you want to stick to `PCA`.

That said, do you really want to one-hot encode every feature?  And then scale those dummy variables?  Consider using a `ColumnTransformer` if you'd like to encode some features and scale others.